# Is the mastery "Dangerous Game" affected by ignite?

Tags: league-of-legends

One of the new season 4 masteries is:

**Dangerous Game**

`Killing an enemy champion restores 5% of your missing health and mana.`

Is this affected by any healing reducing spells/abilities like Ignite? Or does `restore` mean it will be applied no matter what?

Comment: Though inconclusive, I've seen a few people say that spells/abilities like Ignite do infact effect Dangerous Game. "Restore" seems to mean "heal" in this case.

Comment: i believe grevious wounds/ignite includes anything that gives health back. i.e hp10 and lifesteal and dangerous game.

Comment: The only sort of HP addition that is not affected by ignite is Bonus Health (i.e. Lulu/Nasus/Renek ult).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Wiki page for [Ignite](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Ignite) states:

> reduces healing and regeneration effects on the target by 50% for the duration.

So yes, any masteries that heal including this are affected by ignite.

Any items or champion abilities that apply [Grievous Wounds](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Grievous_Wounds) will add the same heal reduction effect as well to their target.